# Java - Why are my inserts so slow?

Tags: java, mysql

Somehow my MySQL Inserts are really slow. Even when I use "Batch-Inserts". About 50 inserts take up to 2000ms.. Is this normal or is there a way to improve my code?

```
            String sql = "INSERT INTO wlw ( wlw_level, wlw_name, wlw_url, wlw_processing, wlw_finished, wlw_source )"
                        + "VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement preparedStatement = conn.prepareStatement(sql, Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);

            for(QueryStore qs : QueryStore) {
                preparedStatement.setInt(1, qs.level);
                preparedStatement.setString(2, qs.anchor);
                preparedStatement.setString(3, qs.url);
                preparedStatement.setInt(4, qs.processing);
                preparedStatement.setInt(5, qs.finished);
                preparedStatement.setLong(6, qs.id);
                preparedStatement.addBatch();
                System.out.println("Adding URL: " + qs.url);
            }
            System.out.println("Start saving ...");
            long then = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
            preparedStatement.executeBatch();
            long now = then - System.currentTimeMillis();
            System.out.println("SAVING END - Took me " + now + "ms");
```

Thanks for any suggestions!!

Comment: One possible optim. is not using `Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS` as you don't use the returned generated keys.

Comment: it's an innoDB table?

Comment: Are you using a connection pool or creating the connection manually every time you call the method which execute the `INSERT` operation? Has your table any trigger on insert or is any monitor for your tables? How many data are you inserting? How many indexes your table manages? Does it use lot of foreign keys?

Comment: @Khalil Yes, is that a problem?

Comment: @Crayl i think its a problem because when you insert a row into an InnoDB table, innodb engin build the pk and update indexes for that row, and this can slow down your inserts considerably

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `rewriteBatchedStatements=true` to your connection parameters.

Comment: Amazing. Now it's very fast. Thank you very much!